# API Key in microservices

Tags: api, key

Is sending an encrypted connection string as an API Key through headers a good idea?

Someone once told me, storing API Keys in a DB is a bad thing to do but I can't seem to figure out how, when in the end all an attacker has to do is use fiddler to check the headers you are sending in requests for the API Key.

The reason I want to store API Keys in a DB is because I want to create a portal so users can view API keys for specific services of my microservice application. Thus making the API Key readable in plaintext.

Answer (score 1):

For most intents and purposes, its good to think of an API Key as a username/password combination.  The reason it's generally frowned upon to store API keys in the database in a reversible format is because if your database gets breached, it's possible for an attacker to gain access to all of the API keys which are stored in the application, and impersonate other users.

Showing users their API keys in plain text is essentially the same as showing them their passwords in plain text.  A more secure alternative might be just allowing them to reset their API keys, and not showing them what the original key was.

Comment: Agreed. This is why most services like AWS, GitHub etc, will only let you see your API key once (when the key is generated) and never after that. You can always invalidate old keys and re-generate new keys, but never will you be able to see the cleartext key again.

Comment: I don't entirely agree. API keys are not as sensitive as passwords. It is certainly true that someone who manages to steal keys out of the database will be able to login as the user. However, that doesn't stop plenty of people from storing, say, cookie information in a database.

Comment: The reason we use one way hashing for passwords in databases is not strictly to stop an attacker from finding the password and logging in (although that is a factor). The main reason we hash passwords is to protect the actual password in the event of a breach because so many users reuse passwords. This is not an issue with API keys. So while a stolen API key will allow an attacker in, a stolen password will allow the attacker in, and also allow them to access Facebook, email, etc for the user. Passwords are much more sensitive than API keys.

Comment: @keithRozario they show you the key once, but you have to store somewhere in your side in clear.